# Angular parent animation is not rendered when executed together with a child animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have an Angular application where I have to render two animations at the same time (changing a tab selection while changing the height of a card).

The first animation is rendered inside a component with dynamic states, since the number of tabs is not known upfront:

```
<div [@tabTransition]="{value: currentSelection, params: {position: currentSelection * 100}}"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  animations: [
    trigger('tabTransition', [
      state('*',
        style({transform: 'translateX({{position}}%)'}),
        {params: { position: 0 }}
      ),
      transition('*=>*', [
        group([
          animate('700ms ease'),
          query('@*', [
            animateChild()
          ], {optional: true})
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public currentSelection = 0;
  // ...
  public changeTab(tabIndex: number): void {
    this.currentSelection = tabIndex;
  }
  // ...
}
```

The other component that contains an animation is found inside the `<router-outlet>` (basically we are also navigating to it while rendering the animation).

This only has two states: with or without footer.

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  animations: [
    trigger('cardTransition', [
      state('withFooter',
        style({ height: 'calc(100% - 88px)' })
      ),
      state('withoutFooter',
        style({ height: '100%' })
      ),
      transition('withFooter=>withoutFooter', animate('700ms ease')),
      transition('withoutFooter=>withFooter', animate('700ms ease'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent {

  public shouldDisplayFooter = false; // this value is retrieved through a subscription

  public getCardTransition(): string {
    if (this.shouldDisplayFooter) {
      return 'withFooter';
    }
    return 'withoutFooter';
  }

}
```

```
<div [@cardTransition]="getCardTransition()">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The problem is that only the animation in the "child" component is rendered while for the one in the "parent" component I only see the final state, without any animation.
I also tried naming the states the same, but this doesn't have any effect.